# Can a virus on a flash drive run itself without autorun?

Tags: windows-7, security, autorun

Someone told me that it's possible for a virus to run itself from Flash memories even if `autorun.inf` is not present or this feature is disabled using `gpedit.msc`.  He said a virus can run itself as soon as I plug in a flash memory.  Is it correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [can a virus execute by itself?](http://superuser.com/questions/87242/can-a-virus-execute-by-itself)

Comment: @techie007 Not exactly. This question is specific about beeing run from a flash drive where the other question is more general.

Comment: @techie007 I found  and read that question before asking this one. but my question was about flash drives because I haven't installed virus scan and just disabled autorun feature.

Comment: Tom is kind of correct. This question is asking about the danger of a virus on a (flash) drive spontaneously running itself while the other is asking about the specific existence of such a virus. They are definitely related, but slightly different. I don’t know if the difference is sufficient to justify two separate questions though.

Comment: I think it is related but definitely not the same, Windows performs actions on a flash memory stick when it is inserted that just don't happen with a HDD. The additional wording of the question refers specifically to the events that occur when a flash memory stick is inserted.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## Short answer

No, a file on a drive cannot just run itself. Like all viruses, it needs *some* sort of initialization. A file does not magically initiate for no reason at all; *something* has to cause it to load in *some* way. (Unfortunately the number of ways is bafflingly large and continues to grow.)

## Overview

How a virus runs depends largely on the *type* of file that the virus is in. For example, `.exe` files *usually* require something to actually load their code (simply reading their contents is not enough). Picture or audio files are not supposed to be code at all, so they *should* not be “running” in the first place.

## Technical

What often happens these days, is that there are two main methods that malware runs:

1. Trojans
2. Exploits

**Trojans:**
With trojans, malware code is inserted into normal files. For example a game or program will have some bad code injected into so that when you (purposely) run the program, the bad code sneaks in (hence the name *trojan*). This requires placing the code in an executable. Again, this requires the host program to be specifically run somehow.

**Exploits:**
With exploits, what happens is that a file contains incorrect/invalid structures that *exploit* poor programming. For example, a graphics-viewer program that does not check the picture file may be exploited by crafting a picture file with system code in such a way that when it is read, it overloads the buffer created for the image and tricks the system into passing control to the virus code that was inserted past the buffer (buffer overflows are still fairly popular). This method does *not* require a file with malware code to be specifically *run*; it exploits the bad programming and error checking to trick the system into “running” it simply by opening/reading the file.

## Application

So how does this apply to a flash (or any other type of) drive? If the drive contains trojans (executable files), then unless the system has AutoPlay enabled or has some sort of autorun/startup entry pointing to the file, then no, it should not run on its own. On the other hand, if there are files that exploit vulnerabilities in the operating system or other program, then simply reading/viewing the file could allow the malware to initiate.

## Prevention

A good way to check for vectors by which trojans can run is to check for different kinds of autorun/startup locations. [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) is an easy way to check many of them (it’s even easier if you hide the Windows entries to reduce the clutter). A good way to reduce the number of vulnerabilities that exploits can use is to keep your operating system and program up-to-date with the latest versions and patches.

Comment: You need another `\subsubsection` and a couple other `subsubsubsection`s, this is nowhere near enough. :P

Comment: Exploits also generally only work (properly) with a single viewer application, and sometimes even just with a single version. *For example*, if a bug causes MS Word to be exploitable in a certain way, OpenOffice is likely to remain unaffected (or to be affected in a very different way if the bug is triggered). Exploiting features-by-design (executable code in PDFs, ActiveX on web pages viewed using MSIE, etc) is of course a different beast.

Comment: One thing to refrence for a example of exploit viruses is how [Stuxnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuxnet) exploited a bug in the way windows handled `.lnk` (shortcut) files. So just viewing the directory in windows explorer triggered the virus infection.

Comment: `Exploits also generally only work (properly) with a single viewer application, and sometimes even just with a single version.`   Thankfully yes, though bugs can go undetected/unfixed for a while and thus an vulnerability can be exploited for many versions.     ` So just viewing the directory in windows explorer triggered the virus infection.`   Yes, that’s exactly the sort of vulnerability that exploits, well, exploit. You don’t have to actually *run* a file to get infected anymore because simply *accessing* it (which even viewing a directory listing does) can potentially infect you. ◔̯◔

Answer (score 8):

This depends on how the virus is written,  and what vulnerabilities exist on the system that you plug the drive into,  but the answer is potentially yes.

For example not long ago there was vulnerability inherited way that Windows handled `.lnk` files that meant that just having a maliciously created file on your drive could execute the virus embedded within it. This vulnerability was also fixed quite some time ago so no up to date system should be at risk but it does show that there are potential attack vectors that are "silent" and can happen, as your friend suggests, without your consent or awareness.

Keep your antiviral running and up to date and only connect devices from people you trust.

You can see information on this particular attack method on [this Microsoft page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2286198).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, a virus can propagate simply by inserting a USB device (including a flash drive).

This is because there is code (called firmware) on the USB device that must run for the device to be detected.  This firmware can do things like imitate a keyboard (and thus run a program), imitate a network card, etc.

Look into "BadUSB" for more information.

Answer (score 3):

#### No.

The *virus* can't run *itself* in *any* case. Something *else* needs to run it.

So now the question is: Can it *be run* when plugged in? The answer is "no" in the ideal case, but "**possibly**" in the case of a defect in Explorer (or some other Windows component). However, such a behavior would be a bug in Windows, not by design.

Comment: Bugs in software are very often used as exploit vectors by self-propagating viruses. (I dare say no programmer *deliberately* puts bugs in production software.) Some security holes can stem from features that are by design, such as the long-lasting security problems with ActiveX.

Comment: This is how Stuxnet infected computers. By merely viewing the icon of the infected file, that triggered a vulnerability and started execution of the code.

Comment: I think it’s obvious that the OP is concerned with being infected without any action on his/her part, and not with what part of Windows will be responsible for executing the malicious code. All viruses infect computers by exploiting a vulnerability in existing systems. Even the ones like .exe files that the user clicks on.

Comment: @Emil: Nobody was claiming OP was concerned with what "part" of Windows would be executing the code, either. The discussion was about whether Windows allows this by-design or not. Many laymen may reasonably assume yes; I pointed out the answer is no, unless there's a defect. This is no different than "can my battery catch fire if I leave it in the charger even after it's fully charged." The answer is "no it can't, unless there's a defect in one of them."

Answer (score 2):

Well... hopefully not currently. Any time information in a file of any type is read, there is also the remote chance that the program reading it has some defect that the virus attempts to take advantage of, and either run directly or indirectly. One older example was a jpg virus that took advantage of some sort of buffer overrun in the image viewer. Its a constant task for the people who product antivirus software to find new viruses and provide updates. So if your have all the current antivirus updates and system patches, its probably not an issue today, but a theortical maybe tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

On a clean system, I would say that a virus can't run itself.  But I think that a program could be written that could be running all the time, just waiting for a drive to be inserted, then look for a certain file and run it, if available.  This is pretty unlikely, as the program would need to be installed to run all the time, but it does seem to be within the realm of possible but not very likely.